# Why might $\langle a^2, b\rangle$ be unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Why might the subgroup $H=\langle a^2, b \rangle \triangleleft \langle a, b \mid a^4 = b^{17} = 1, aba^{-1} = b^{-1}\rangle = G$ be the unique subgroup of index $2$?

I've tried some arguments I've seen on here; if $K$ is another such subgroup then I can show that $\langle a^2, b\rangle \cap K$ has order $17$, but I'm not sure how to proceed to a contradiction from this fact (or if one can).

Also, since $\langle a^2, b \rangle$ is normal, it's the kernel of a homomorphism $\phi : G \to \Bbb Z/(2)$, so presumably I might be able to show that there is only one such homomorphism? Otherwise I'm not entirely sure how I might prove this. Unless it's wrong or entirely trivial and I've missed the point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any subgroup of index $2$ is normal, and any homomoprhism $\phi\colon G\to \Bbb Z/(2)$ is determined by its values at $a$ and $b$.
If $\phi(b)=1+2\Bbb Z$ then $\phi(b^{17})=1+2\Bbb Z$, contradiction. Hence $b\in \ker\phi$.
If also $a\in\ker\phi$, then $\phi=0$, which we do not want. Hence $a\notin\ker \phi$.
We now know $\phi$ completely and see that $\ker\phi=\langle a^2,b\rangle$.

Comment: Why is $\phi$ trivial if $a$ is in the kernel? Edit: just understood why!

Answer (score 3):

Good job figuring out that the subgroup $A$ generated by $b$ must be $\le K$.

If you have covered the correspondence theorem then you can argue as follows (justify the claims).

1. The subgroup $A=\langle b\rangle\unlhd G$.
2. $G/A\simeq C_4$.
3. By correspondence theorem the subgroups of $G$ containing $A$ are in bijective correspondence with subgroups of $G/A$.
4. $G/A$ has only a single subgroup of index two.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $H$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $G$, then $x^2 \in H$ for all $x \in G$.